# Use ReSharper to arrange members in the same order as implemented interface

Tags: c#, resharper

Is it possible to use the Type Layout feature of ReSharper to sort the members that implements an interface in the same order as they were declared in the interface?

Comment: No, but you can rearrange members in interface and in implementation by same rules

Answer (score 5):

No, unfortunately you can't do that directly. But, like Kirill said, you can use the same rules to let them order.

Additionally you can let Resharper group members of an interface into one region by modifying the CodeCleanup profile:

```xml
<Group>
    <ImplementsInterface Immediate="true" Region="${ImplementsInterface} Members"/>
</Group>
```

see also: [Resharper Doc](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Cleanup__Usage_Scenarios__Reordering_Type_Members.html)

After the automatic grouping and sorting you can adjust the result via the Resharper "File Structure".