# Is it possible to re-order a class to match the order of elements in its interface using ReSharper (or another tool)?

Tags: c#, resharper

My current code has a class inheriting from an interface but the order of the elements in the interface is currently completely different than the order of elements in its implementation. I would like these to match but could not find a way to do it with ReSharper.

This interface currently has regions as well and I would like to match the same in the implementation as well. I know regions are in general not a good idea but this one is a special case where it is helpful as the class has got a lot of properties that relate to different regions of a screen and being a view-model in MVVM pattern it would be hard to break it down into separate classes.

So, as an example, this would be my interface:

```
public interface IMyBusyViewModel
{
     #region Screen Area 1

     bool PropertyOne { get; set; }

     string PropertyTwo { get; set; }

     #endregion

     #region Screen Area 2

     bool PropertyThree { get; set; }

     string PropertyFour { get; set; }

     #endregion
}
```

And this would be my current implementation:

```
internal class MyBusyViewModel : IMyBusyViewModel
{
     string PropertyTwo { get; set; }

     string PropertyFour { get; set; }

     bool PropertyOne { get; set; }

     bool PropertyThree { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the outcome I would like to have on the implementation:

```
internal class MyBusyViewModel : IMyBusyViewModel
{
     #region Screen Area 1

     bool PropertyOne { get; set; }

     string PropertyTwo { get; set; }

     #endregion

     #region Screen Area 2

     bool PropertyThree { get; set; }

     string PropertyFour { get; set; }

     #endregion
}
```

To clarify a bit, I can't use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393043/use-resharper-to-arrange-members-in-the-same-order-as-implemented-interface) because the items in the interface are ordered in a way that is practically impossible to get ReSharper to do automatically.

Thanks!

Comment: Delete all the members which implements interface and regenerate it(via implement interface feature)? You'll get it in order though you won't get `#region` thing..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no auto rearrange refactoring.

But you can cheat and delete all your properties in the MyBusyViewModel, after resharper would give your red squiggly underneach the IMyBusyViewModel place a cursor on the interface and press ALT+Enter followed by Enter and it will recreate all properties in order.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that but since all methods and properties have been actually implemented already after deleting and re-implementing I would have to copy the actual implementation over... I mean, possible but laborious; I was hoping there was a simpler way.